# SVG website background not appearing on lower resolution screens

Tags: svg

I have an animated SVG that I'm using as a background on a website. It work fine on screen with at least QHD resolution, however on anything with 1080p or lower, the SVG doesn't show at all.

https://entofm.co.uk/beta

Comment: It is hard to help without any clues. Maybe you can point to the specific code either by including it in your question or by explaining what it is that we are searching for. You have a responsive design. Could it be the case that the background is removed or overwritten when you have a smaller screen?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.